# using third part modules in IBM quantum experience (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

Is there any option to use **Tensorflow** in **IBM quantum experience**? I have searched on google but I couldn't find anything. I thought about copying the source code, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use Tensorflow in Qiskit, IBM's Quantum software development kit. You can look at this blog post about it: https://towardsdatascience.com/integrating-tensorflow-and-qiskit-for-quantum-machine-learning-7fa6b14d5294 , where they use a machine learning package Tensorflow Quantum designed to work with programs like Qiskit. You can also use it in a jupyter notebook in the Quantum Lab tab of IBM Quantum Experience. If you look up using Tensorflow with Qiskit, you will get more results on Google.